# How to extracting the XML contents of an XDocument variable?

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the a full XML file in an XDocument variable which I get from some API like this

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("website"))
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        }
```

I need to get the structure of the XML and navigate through its nodes, but through the XDocument variable, I only get the whole document in one node and can not extract each node by itself. So any solution or shall I use another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xdoc;
xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(XmlReader.Create("weblink"));
```

The XDocument is not possible to be analyzed and extract its XML values which is possible in XmlDocument

Comment: I think what you need is XDocument.Load(). Which is a STATIC method. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Your method should work as well I guess. But anyway, I don't have to use XDcocument; XmlDocument is simpler so I used it. Thanks for your participation though :)

Comment: I disagree, I find XDocument and XElment far easaier to use as everything is strongly typed. This is more true when you get it driven by an xsd file. when you have time you shuold check it out.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx
is a good article on building it up

you can also use linq to query it

for instance

```
var loaded = XDocument.Load("sdaf");
var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("contact")
        where (int)c.Attribute("contactId") < 4
        select (string)c.Element("firstName") + “ “ +
      (string)c.Element("lastName");
```

taken off the page i linked to above.

The XDocument and XElement objects kick ass in my opinion.
If you dont like them then go learn xpath and xslt.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the immediate child nodes of your `XDocument` you can try

```
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("website"))
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        var childElements = doc.Elements();
    }
```

Then do further processing such as `childElements.Descendants("name").Single().Value`.

Comment: I tried the first part but it didn't work, not sure about the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();

XmlDocument thisXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
thisXmlDoc.LoadXml(xml); // In your case DOC

reader.Close();

XPathNavigator thisNavigator = thisXmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator dossierNodes = thisNavigator.Select("Nodename/node");

List<Dossier> thisList = GetDossiers(dossierNodes);
thisDossierList = thisList.OrderBy(c => c.something).ToList();
```

he is using XDocument objects, not XMLDocument objects. – John Nicholas 52 secs ago

Damn, you're right. Sorry! Only tried to help...

Comment: he is using XDocument objects, not XMLDocument objects.

Comment: nothing wrong with XMLDOcument, it just that it works best with a XPath and XSLT approach. .net only implements xpath 1.0 btw - which really effects what you can do in xslt. Hah i like the way you did that btw. Still prefer linq2xml though.